# Android GridView with database

Tags: android, database, layout, gridview

I've got problem with my grid view. I would like to store images in table and then display them in grid view.

```
 // ImageAdapter

    String[] strings = db.getPictures();
    Integer[] ints = new Integer[strings.length];
    for (int i=0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(strings[i]);
    }
    imageView.setImageResource(ints[position]);
    return imageView;


   //DatabaseHandler

 public String[] getPictures(){
    int i=0;

    String selectQuery = "SELECT pictureName FROM Category";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    int rowsNumber=c.getCount();
    String[] mThumbIds;
    mThumbIds= new String[rowsNumber];

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            mThumbIds[i]=c.getString(0);
            i++;
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    return mThumbIds;
}
```

And when i run my app it crush at starting. Single string I save like `R.drawable.ic_work`

Comment: I guess the error is **Resource not found**

Comment: try Integer.parseInt("ff0000", 16), you need to parse into a hex int

Comment: Yes, log shows java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "R.drawable.ic_job"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said you are saving `R.drawable.ic_work` as string.

**The problem** is you are using `imageView.setImageResource(ints[position]);` while `R.drawable.ic_work` is String.

**Solution** is instead of storing `R.drawable.ic_work` as `String` store it as `int` because your `R.drawable.ic_work` represents with an `int ID`.

Comment: I've changed my string into int references to resource. So now I'm storing not R.drawable.ic_work but 2130837514. And it works.

Answer (score 1):

In most scenarios, your device wont be able to load a single original image into memory leave alone a list. You need to scale your image before you display it.